# Custom linker for Xcode project with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, build, linker, clang

We use LD and LDPLUSPLUS user settings to invoke custom linker, which works fine unless there's a swift file in the project and then the original clang is invoked. Is there any way to override linker for projects that use swift?

**Update:** a radar for the Xcode bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5330879249383424

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have easier time using a makefile-based project with custom compilers and linkers.

http://owensd.io/2015/01/14/compiling-swift-without-xcode.html - on compiling swift without xcode.